# Coding for Seeed Arduino motor shield

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

I acquired a Seeed studio Arduino motor shield V.2 and wanted to start using it. The problem is that there is like no good example code. The library for the shield on the seeed website has one example and doesn't really explain anything. Does anybody know where I could get a good guide for this thing?